# Is a submersion times interval still a submersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

this question is a bit stupid and I think I only need some confirmation. But as is well known we have a riemannian submersion from $S^{2n+1} \to CP^n$. If we take an intervall $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, is it true that $I\times S^{2n+1} \to CP^n$ is also a riemannian submersion ? (For a metric of the form $a^2(t)dt^2+g$ where $g$ is the metric on the sphere, $a$ a smooth function)

I would say the obvious answer is yes but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Which part of the definition are you having trouble verifying?

Comment: What is the mapping?

Comment: Well actually I think I know how to show it. I'm just not 100% certain that my reasoning is correct or that the statement holds.

Comment: The mapping is just $(t,z) \to \pi(z)$ for $(t,z) \in I \times S^{2n+1}$ and $\pi: S^{2n+1} \to CP^n$. I mean since the tangent space of products is the product of the tangent spaces this should be a submersion right ?

Comment: In general, if you have $f\colon X\to Y$ a submersion and you define $F\colon X\times Z\to Y$ by $F(x,z)=f(x)$, isn't it immediately still a submersion? Just write down the definition.